# Show multi-elements asynchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multi div like

```
<div class="a">a1</div>
<div class="a">a2</div>
.....

.a{display: none}
```

I try to show all of them by way:
show direct a div when it complete one by one when all is show(it mean show one after other complete)

I try but it not working. How to do that thank

```
function test(child) {
    setTimeout(function(child) {
        child.show();
        // this mean i don't know when a div finish show, it defend my caculate
        for (var i = 0; i < 5000000*random_number; i++) {
            var x = 0;
        }
    }, 0);
}
$(".a").each(function( index ) {
    test($(thís));
});
```

Comment: `make a sleep` - **never** do that - you have `setTimeout` of `0` ... and then introduce that loop? perhaps you need to read up on setTimeout

Comment: you mean showing one after another?

Comment: @azad yes, i want show one after another complele

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry i just update

Comment: you updated the code, by removing the **comment**, yet still doing the wrong thing? Obviously you didn't understand what the issue I was pointing out was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, inside jquery callback function check next sibling

```js
$(function() {

  var showTime = 1000;

  $($('.a')[0]).show(showTime, showNextDiv.bind(null, $($('.a')[0])))

  function showNextDiv($elem) {

    var el = $elem.next('.a')[0];

    $(el).show(showTime, showNextDiv.bind(null, $(el)))

  }

})
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'>test</div>
<div class='a'>test</div>
<div class='a'>test</div>
<div class='a'>test</div>
<div class='a'>test</div>
```

Comment: I look good, but i don't know when a div finish show (it depend by caculate)

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```js
    $(function() {
        $(".a").each(function(index) {
            setTimeout(function(e) {
                e.fadeIn();
            }, index * 1000, $(this));
        });
    });
```

```css
.a {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">a1</div>
<div class="a">a2</div>
<div class="a">a3</div>
<div class="a">a4</div>
<div class="a">a5</div>
<div class="a">a6</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain JS:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

  setTimeout(TurnOnDiv.bind(null, i), (1000 * i));
}

function TurnOnDiv(i) {

  divs[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.a{display: none}
```

```html
<div class="a">a1</div>
<div class="a">a2</div>
<div class="a">a3</div>
<div class="a">a4</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/q75a20L8/

```js
var showDiv = function(that){
  $(that).slideDown();
  setTimeout(function(){
    if($(that).next('div.a').length){
      showDiv($(that).next('div.a'));
    }
  }, 500)
}

showDiv($('.a').first());
```

```css
.a{display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">a1</div>
<div class="a">a2</div>
<div class="a">a3</div>
<div class="a">a4</div>
<div class="a">a5</div>
<div class="a">a6</div>
```

Wrap the show method in a function & call the first instance separately, then check for next element.

If next element present then call the function with next instance.

I've used `jQuery` `slideDown` instead of `show`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to show them one by one, with 500ms interval:

```
function showNextDiv() {
  const $div = $('.a').eq(0);
  if (!$div.length) {
    return;
  }
  $div.removeClass('a');
  setTimeout(showNextDiv, 500);
}
showNextDiv();
```